# PHP Group array of postcodes by their 4 for letters PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Can't get my head around a simple way to do this. I'm creating the end point on an API for some graph data and need to create a response that contains an array of labels and another array for the values.

I already have the array of postcodes, what I want to do I be able to have a new array that contains the postcodes grouped by the first 4 characters with a sub array of all of the postcodes of that group so I can count the array length for the values.

E.g. output:

```
$postcodes = ['SO30 0NG', 'SO30 OTD', 'SO31 1TG', 'RG51 5HG', 'RG51 7GH']

$grouped = [
    'SO30' = [
        'SO30', 'SO30'
    ],
    'SO31' = [
        'SO31'        
    ],
    'RG51' = [
        'RG51', 'RG51'        
    ]
]
```

My first attempt was:

```
foreach ($postcode as $pc) {
    $cleanPostcode = str_replace(" ", "", $pc);
    $cleanPostcode = substr($cleanPostcode, 0, 4);
    $data[$cleanPostcode][] = $cleanPostcode;
}
```

But this seemed to create duplicate keys.

Comment: Are you sure that's how you want `$grouped` to look? Shouldn't it be the full postcodes in the sub-arrays, not just the prefix? Your current code produces an array identical to `$grouped` at the moment: https://eval.in/874249

Comment: What keys are duplicated, where? If you only want to count how many times these four letter prefixes occur, then you do you put the same value into the arrays multiple times, instead of just increasing a counter variable?

Comment: You've trimmed cleanpostcode to four characters using substring.. try making that a separate variable

Comment: You also seem to have forgotten about post codes with only 3 chars like `SO1 9XX`

Comment: `$cleanPostcodeShort = substr...`
`$data[$cleanPostcodeShort][] = $cleanPostcode;`

Comment: @Lovelock Are you expecting something like this? https://eval.in/874254

Comment: @Lovelock Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Do you actually just want to count the number of occurrences of the postcode prefixes, which can be done much more simply than via constructing a new, nested array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
$postcodes = ['SO30 0NG', 'SO30 OTD', 'SO31 1TG', 'RG51 5HG', 'RG51 7GH'];

$result= array();
Foreach ($postcodes as $postcode){
    $short =Substr($postcode,0,4);
    // If subarray does not exist
    If(!isset($result[$short])) $result[$short]=[]; //create subarray of short in result

    $result[$short][]= $short; // add item in subarray
}

Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/YG08d

Comment: `If(!isset($result[$short])) $result[$short]=[];` is not needed because  child elements can be pushed with square brace syntax without explicitly declaring their parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($postcode as $pc) {
    $cleanPostcode = str_replace(" ", "", $pc);
    $cleanPostcodeShort = substr($cleanPostcode, 0, 4);
    $data[$cleanPostcodeShort][] = $cleanPostcode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
$postcodes = ['SO30 0NG', 'SO30 OTD', 'SO31 1TG', 'RG51 5HG', 'RG51 7GH'];
$grouped = [];
foreach ($postcodes as $pc) {
    $group = explode(" ", $pc);
    $grouped[$group[0]][] = $group[1];
}

var_dump($grouped)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$postcodes = ['SO30 0NG', 'SO30 OTD', 'SO31 1TG', 'RG51 5HG', 'RG51 7GH'];

$output = [];

foreach($postcodes as $postcode)
{
    $splitPostcode = explode(' ', $postcode);

    if(!array_key_exists($splitPostcode[0], $output))
    {
        $output[$splitPostcode[0]] = [];
    }

    $output[$splitPostcode[0]][] = $splitPostcode[0];
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **OP says**: I want to do I be able to have a new array that contains the postcodes grouped by the first 4 characters with a sub array of all of the postcodes of that group so I can count the array length for the values.

Since the goal is merely to count the occurrences of the substrings before the first space, then you can avoid the grouping step by truncating the values and counting the values.

*note: [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) with a `true` value in the third parameter will isolate the string prior to the value in the second parameter.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ccc060441c337f65efbeaeb9fe6d63240cf31f4e))

```
$postcodes = ['SO30 0NG', 'SO30 OTD', 'SO31 1TG', 'RG51 5HG', 'RG51 7GH'];

$postcode_counts = array_count_values(array_map(function($v){ return strstr($v, ' ', true);}, $postcodes));

var_export($postcode_counts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'SO30' => 2,
  'SO31' => 1,
  'RG51' => 2,
)
```